# Unable to get image in React Native IOS app

Tags: react-native, jsx

I am trying to display a image on IOS app. Image does not showing.But there is no warning in simulator but in debugger is  am getting this error.

> RCTLog.js:46 Module RCTImageLoader requires main queue setup since it overrides `init` but doesn't implement `requiresMainQueueSetup`. In a future release React Native will default to initializing all native modules on a background thread unless explicitly opted-out of.

I don't know if it is a bug or not. But how can I display a simple image?

```
<Vew>
   <Image source={{uri: 'my image url'}} />
</View>
```

Comment: try add style to image

Answer (score 1):

in react-native remote images are required to set width and height explicitly

```
<View>
    <Image source={{uri: 'my image url'}} style={{width:300 ,height :300}}/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error was in the image url. I have to disable App Transport Security for that particular domain because its a non secure http domain not https.